# JavaScript Rock, Paper, Scissors - Adding 1 after each victory

Tags: javascript

Every time that humanity or AI win I want it to increment by one but instead it only increments to 1 once and then doesn't ever go past 1.

```
let Humanity = 0;
let AI = 0;

//Create function to generate random computer choice 

function getComputerChoice() { 

    const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    const randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    const decision = choices[randomChoice];
    return decision;

 } getComputerChoice();

 //play a round of game


 function round() {

    let computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    let playerDecision = prompt('Make your decision!', '').toLowerCase();


    if (playerDecision === 'rock' && computerChoice === 'scissors') {
        Humanity += 1;
        alert('Humanity wins' + ' ' + 'your score is' + ' ' + Humanity);
    } else if (playerDecision === 'scissors' && computerChoice === 'paper') {
        Humanity += 1;
        alert('Humanity wins' + ' ' + 'your score is' + ' ' + Humanity);
    } else if (playerDecision === 'paper' && computerChoice === 'rock') {
        Humanity += 1;
        alert('Humanity wins' + ' ' + 'your score is' + ' ' + Humanity);
    } else if (playerDecision === 'rock' && computerChoice === 'paper') {
        AI += 1;
        alert('AI wins' + ' ' + 'AIs score is' + ' ' + AI);
    } else if (playerDecision === 'scissors' && computerChoice === 'rock') {
        AI += 1;
        alert('AI wins' + ' ' + 'AIs score is' + ' ' + AI);
    } else if (playerDecision === 'paper' && computerChoice === 'scissors') {
        AI += 1;
        alert('AI wins' + ' ' + 'AIs score is' + ' ' + AI);
    } else if (playerDecision === computerChoice) {
        alert('It is a tie' + ' ' + 'the score is' + ' ' + 'AI' + ' ' + AI + ' ' + 'Humanity' + ' ' + Humanity );
    } else if (playerDecision != 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors') {
        alert('Invalid, do not tempt me human!')
    } 

 } round();
```

I expect is to increment up by 1 every time humanity or AI win.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to call the function again at the end to restart the game?

```
..........

    } else if (playerDecision != 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors') {
        alert('Invalid, do not tempt me human!')
    } 

    // Add another call here
    round()

 } round();
```

Good luck!

Comment: that works thank you for the help! Does this work because the function is called and then it calls itself again before it exits so it just restarts the function?

Comment: @Pete1230z  Exactly. Else the functions just ends